# Replace many strings by their counterparts according to a mapping

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings (e.g. country names), and a mapping of those strings to other strings (e.g. a mapping of country names to iso codes).

```
countries = c('United States', 'Ecuador', 'Russia', 'Russia', 'Ecuador')
mapping = data.frame(country = c('Ecuador', 'Russia', 'United States'),
                     iso3 = c('ECU', 'RUS', 'USA'))
```

How can I replace all occurences of country names in `countries` by the respective iso codes according to `mapping`?

Comment: You can use `factor` and `levels`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, as Justin pointed out:

```
factor(countries,levels = mapping$country,labels = mapping$iso3)
[1] USA ECU RUS RUS ECU
Levels: ECU RUS USA
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this answer because it helped me to realize that I should be using factors for this variable. @Matthews answer works just as well, however.

Answer (score 8):

This is one way:

```
with(mapping, iso3[match(countries, country)])
# [1] USA ECU RUS RUS ECU
# Levels: ECU RUS USA
```

Wrap this in `as.character` to the result as a character vector.