# Replace words in corpus according to dictionary data frame

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I am interested in replacing all words in a `tm` Corpus object according to a dictionary made of a two columns data frame, where the first column is the word to be matched and the second column is the replacement word.

I am stuck with the `translate` function. I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110944/1707938) but I can't transform it in a function to be passed to `tm_map`.

Please consider the following MWE

```
library(tm)

docs <- c("first text", "second text")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))

dictionary <- data.frame(word = c('first', 'second', 'text'),
                      translation = c('primo', 'secondo', 'testo'))

translate <- function(text, dictionary) {
  # Would like to replace each word of text with corresponding word in dictionary
}

corp_translated <- tm_map (corp, translate)

inspect(corp_translated)

# Expected result

# A corpus with 2 text documents
#
# The metadata consists of 2 tag-value pairs and a data frame
# Available tags are:
#   create_date creator 
# Available variables in the data frame are:
#   MetaID 

# [[1]]
# primo testo

# [[2]]
# secondo testo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest *not* using a `data.frame` for a dictionary, since the basic object in `R`, a vector, is a dictionary by default.

```
      dict  <- c('primo', 'secondo', 'testo')
names(dict) <- c('first', 'second', 'text')
```

Then to `"tanslate"` `x`, where `x` might be `"second"`, you simply use:

```
   dict[[x]]
```

You dont even need a wrapper function.

---

If you want to translate in the opposite direction, use

```
   name(dict)[names(dict) %in% x]
```

Or you can flip the dictionary

```
         dict.flip  <- names(dict)
   names(dict.flip) <- dict
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to operationalize `dict[[x]]`. Let's say I have a string `str = "First Second Text"` how should I translate it with `dict[[x]]`?

Comment: I think they need `gsub` here.

Comment: if you didnt yet split your text into individual words, you would need to do that first:   `TEXT.split <- strsplit(TEXT, "\\s")`   If you dont have translations for all words, then you need some form of logic.  Use `ifelse` (slow) or `match` or `%in%`

Answer (score 3):

In combination with the `tm_map` function of the `tm` package, you can use `stri_replace_all_fixed` from package `stringi`. For instance:

```
library(tm)
library(stringi)

docs <- c("first text", "second text")
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(docs))

word <- c('first', 'second', 'text')
tran <- c('primo', 'secondo', 'testo')

corp <- tm_map(corp, function(x) stri_replace_all_fixed(x, word, tran, vectorize_all = FALSE))
```