# Use mapply to replace a patterns in a vector with replacements in a vector in tm

Tags: r, gsub, tm, mapply

Hi there: I m using the tm package for some text analysis and I need to sub a vector of terms with the paired replacement term in a vector of replacements. So the pattern / replacement dictionary looks like this.

```
#pattern -replacement dictionary
df<-data.frame(replace=c('crude', 'oil', 'price'), with=c('xcrude', 'xoil', 'xprice'))
#load tm
library(tm)
#load crude
data('crude')
```

I tried this and received an error

```
tm_map(crude, mapply, gsub, df$replace, df$with)

Warning message:
In mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) :
all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

Comment: Do you have to do it with `tm`?

Comment: Basically yes. I'm pretty sure I could do this outside of it, but I'd like to know how to do it in tm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580002/replace-words-in-corpus-according-to-dictionary-data-frame/32538367#32538367) you could use `stringi` and wrap it around `content_transformer()` to preserve the corpus structure:

```
corp <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(
  function(x) { 
    stri_replace_all_fixed(x, df$replace, df$with, vectorize_all = FALSE) 
    })
  )
```

Or `multigsub` from `qdap`

```
corp <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(
  function(x) { 
    multigsub(df$replace, df$with, fixed = FALSE, x) 
    })
  )
```

Which gives:

```
> corp[[1]][1]
```

> "Diamond Shamrock Corp said that\neffective today it had cut its
>   contract **xprices** for **xcrude xoil** by\n1.50 dlrs a barrel.\n The reduction brings its posted **xprice** for West Texas\nIntermediate to
>   16.00 dlrs a barrel, the copany said.\n    \"The **xprice** reduction today was made in the light of falling\n**xoil** product **xprices**
>   and a weak **xcrude xoil** market,\" a company\nspokeswoman said.\n
>   Diamond is the latest in a line of U.S. **xoil** companies that\nhave
>   cut its contract, or posted, **xprices** over the last two
>   days\nciting weak **xoil** markets.\n Reuter"

You can then apply other `tm` functions on the resulting corpus:

```
> DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
#<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 20, terms: 1269)>>
#Non-/sparse entries: 2262/23118
#Sparsity           : 91%
#Maximal term length: 17
#Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: And if the dictionary of terms to be replaced is actually regular expressions, then I would use:

stri_replace_all_regex

Comment: So, this only partially working.  When you check the structure of what this returns, it's a list, not a corpus.
#Check structure
str(corp)
str(crude)

#Check class this is the same
class(corp)
class(crude)

I think this is significant because now basic functions like a  DocumentTermMatrix now longer work>
#DTM
DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
DocumentTermMatrix(crude)